# Bessel functions of different orders orthogonality

Tags: integration, orthogonality, bessel-functions

It is known that
$$
 \int_0^\infty\!J_m(ar)\,J_m(br)\,r\,dr = \frac{\delta(a-b)}{a}
$$

Is there a similar equation for

$$
 \int_0^\infty\!J_{m-1}(ar)\,J_{m+1}(br)\,r\,dr\;\text?
$$

Are the Bessel functions of orders $m\!-\!1$ and $m\!+\!1$ orthogonal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not orthogonal in general.  Using the recurrence relationship

$$J_{n+1}(x)+J_{n-1}(x)=\frac{2n}{x}J_n(x)$$

we see that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty J_{m-1}(ar)J_{m+1}(br)\,r\,dr&=\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{2m}{ar}J_m(ar)-J_{m+1}(ar)\right)J_{m+1}(br)\,r\,dr\\\\
&=\frac{2m}{a}\int_0^\infty J_m(ar)J_{m+1}(br)\,dr-\int_0^\infty J_{m+1}(ar) J_{m+1}(br)\,r\,dr\\\\
&=\frac{2m}{a}\int_0^\infty J_m(ar)J_{m+1}(br)\,dr-\frac{\delta(a-b)}{a}\tag 1
\end{align}$$

The first integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ is not equal to $0$ in general.  For example, with $m=1$, $a=2$, and $b=5$ its value is $\frac{2}{25}\ne 0$.

Comment: Makes sense. But how does it relate to this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2221169/88467?

Comment: And can you briefly explain how do you calculate the integral $\int J_m J_{m+1}$?

Comment: We need not evaluate the general form to show that the integral fails to vanish for some $m$, some $a$, and some $b$.  Try to evaluate the integral for $m=1$ and integer values of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if there is an analytical solution of this integral for integer $m$?