# Orthogonality of Bessel functions with different indices

Tags: integration, special-functions, bessel-functions

We know that for Bessel functions with same index the orthogonality condition holds:
$$
\int_0^{+\infty}J_\mu(k x)J_\mu(k' x) k' x dx=\delta(k-k')
$$
Is it possible to obtain an analytic result for($\mu \neq\nu$)?
$$
I=\int_0^{+\infty}J_\mu(k x)J_\nu(k' x) k' x dx
$$
In the similar question([Delta-function representations, Bessel function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2011105/delta-function-representations-bessel-function/2221169#2221169)) one of the answers says that it is equal to zero which is dubious.