# How to find $ \lim_{a\to 0+}\int_0^\infty \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{a \sigma(r,\theta)}{\left(a^2+r^2\right)^{3/2}} \, r\,dr \,d\theta $?

Tags: integration, limits

**First version**

How to obtain the limit of this integral? Thank you!
$$
\lim_{a \to 0^{\large +}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}
\frac{a\,\sigma\left(r,\theta\right)}{\left(a^{2} + r^{2}\right)^{3/2}}\, r\,\mathrm{d}r \,\mathrm{d}\theta
$$
I believe we cannot change the order of the integral and limit operators.

**After modified**

This question has its clear geodesy or physical meaning: by setting the areal density is *σ*, the observation point is (*r*=0, θ=0, *z=a*) in column coordinate system, then the gravitation of the whole plane is the given integral if the observation point approach to the plane.

And *σ* is independent of *a*.
If one set *σ=exp(-r)*, the limit return by Mathematica is 2*pi.

In geodesy view, the order of the two integration maybe not important, but we must complete the two-dimensional integration firstly before the limit.

Any help or comment is welcome. Thank you!

**Second version**

I do not know the following is correct or not. Please help me to modify it.
$$
\sigma(r,\theta ) = \sum\limits_m {\int_0^{ + \infty } \Sigma } (\lambda ,m)S(r,\theta ;\lambda ,m)\lambda {\rm{d}}\lambda 
$$

$$
\Sigma(\lambda ,m) = \int_0^{2\pi } {\int_0^{ + \infty } \sigma } (r,\theta ){S^*}(r,\theta ;\lambda ,m)rdrd\theta
$$

$$
S(r,\theta ;\lambda ,m) = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}{J_m}(\lambda r){{\rm{e}}^{{\rm{i}}m\theta }}
$$

and ${J_m}(\lambda r)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind.

Then we may replace the integral by the above expansions as

$$
\begin{array}{l}
g = Ga\int_0^{ + \infty } {\int_0^{2\pi } {\frac{{\sigma (r,\theta )}}{{{{({a^2} + {r^2})}^{3/2}}}}r} {\kern 1pt} drd\theta } \\
 = Ga\int_0^{ + \infty } {\int_0^{2\pi } {\frac{1}{{{{({a^2} + {r^2})}^{3/2}}}}\left[ {\sum\limits_m {\int_0^{ + \infty } \Sigma  } (\lambda ,m)S(r,\theta ;\lambda ,m)\lambda {\rm{d}}\lambda } \right]r} {\kern 1pt} drd\theta } \\
 = Ga\sum\limits_m {\int_0^{ + \infty } \Sigma  } (\lambda ,m)\left[ {\int_0^{2\pi } {\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{S(r,\theta ;\lambda ,m)}}{{{{({a^2} + {r^2})}^{3/2}}}}r} {\kern 1pt} drd\theta } } \right]\lambda d\lambda \\
 = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}Ga\sum\limits_m {\int_0^{ + \infty } \Sigma  } (\lambda ,m)\left[ {\int_0^{2\pi } {\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{J_m}(\lambda r){{\rm{e}}^{im\theta }}}}{{{{({a^2} + {r^2})}^{3/2}}}}r} {\kern 1pt} drd\theta } } \right]\lambda d\lambda \\
 = Ga\int_0^{ + \infty } {\Sigma (\lambda ,0)\left[ {\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{J_0}(\lambda r)\sqrt {2\pi } }}{{{{({a^2} + {r^2})}^{3/2}}}}rdr} } \right]\lambda d\lambda } \\
 = \sqrt {2\pi } Ga\int_0^{ + \infty } {\Sigma (\lambda ,0)\frac{{{{\rm{e}}^{ - a\lambda }}}}{a}\lambda d\lambda } \\
 = \sqrt {2\pi } G\int_0^{ + \infty } {\Sigma (\lambda ,0){{\rm{e}}^{ - a\lambda }}\lambda d\lambda } 
\end{array}
$$

with
$$
\Sigma(\lambda ,0) = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}\int_0^{2\pi } {\int_0^{ + \infty } f } (r,\theta ){J_0}(\lambda r)rdrd\theta
$$

If $\sigma(r,\theta)=1$, the limit of this integral should be $2\pi G$. However, the above $\Sigma(\lambda,0)$ is infinity in this case?

Could you help me to fix it? Thank you!

**Third version**

If $\sigma(r,\theta)=1$, then $\Sigma(\lambda ,0) = {\sqrt {2\pi}} {\int_0^{ + \infty }  } {J_0}(\lambda r)rdr=\sqrt {2\pi } \frac{{\delta (\lambda )}}{\lambda }$ [(see here)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2011105/delta-function-representations-bessel-function). So, $g=2\pi G$ in this speical case.

**Rest**

Are All the above formulae are correct? This method is correct or not?

Comment: σ (r=0) is not infinite. (not "infitie", sorry). This function is finite on the entire plane.

Comment: What is "infitie"? And what we know about $\sigma$?

Comment: @zkutch, \sigma is a continuous and finite function on the whole plane. Thank you.

Comment: I think you mean $d\theta\,dr$. The order is important.

Comment: dtheta first, dr second. Thank  you.

Comment: You cannot change the order of the limit and the integral. You have to do "something" with the integral first. I guess it starts with $r=a\tan x$ and then using some properties of $\sigma$: bounded, periodic...?

Comment: If $\sigma$ is only continuous, then taking $\sigma = \left(a^2+r^2\right)^{3/2} \frac{1}{r}$ makes diverges integral. We need something more, then continuous.

Comment: The integral has the following physics meaning: By setting the areal density is \sigma, the observation point is (r=0,\theta=0,a), then the gravitation of the whole plane is the given integral if the observation point approach to the plane. So \sigma is independent of a.

Comment: Please add details by editing your post, not in comments.

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sigma\left(0,\theta\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta$

Comment: @FelixMarin Could you give more details？ Thank you!